# jQuery Mobile 1.4 infinite scrolling: Window scroll not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile 1.4, why isn't `$(window).scroll` firing? Here's a non-working example trying to detect when the user has scrolled to the end of the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/5x6T2/

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("Bottom reached!");
        }
    });
});
```

This was all working fine in jQuery Mobile 1.3 prior to the deprecation of `pageshow`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Demr7/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '.ui-page', function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("Bottom reached!");
        }
    });
});
```

Anybody know what to do?

Comment: You can bind it to a specific page. But as of JQM 1.4.3 that event is deprecated and replaced with pagecontainercreate which can't be bound to a specific page.

Comment: I tried that but it seems `$(window).scroll` will still not fire. I looked into the onPage plugin as described at http://gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile-version-1-4-update/ as well but still no luck.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom using `$(window).scroll` (not `$(document).scroll`) so I can do some infinite scrolling operations.

Comment: you can listen to `scrollstart` and/or `scrollstop`, then calculate `$(window).scrollTop()` if it equals to `$(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $.mobile.getScreenHeight() - toolbars outer height` means you have reached the end of the page. If you want I can post a detailed answer.

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you think it could help? Here's my actual use case on 1.4: http://jsfiddle.net/94hcm/ (here with 1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/pBGU6/)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/r6T8S/show/

Comment: Really nice fiddle thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57276/discussion-between-omar-and-mark-boulder).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have to use any third party *plugin* to achieve *infinity scrolling*. You simply need to listen to either [`scrollstart`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstart/) or [`scrollstop`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/scrollstop/) and do some math.

What you need is `$(window).scrollTop()`, `$.mobile.getScreenHeight()`, `$(".ui-content").outerHeight()`, `$(".ui-header").outerHeight()` and `$(".ui-footer").outerHeight()`.

When `$(window).scrollTop()`'s value matches the value of viewport's height *minus* content div's height *plus* toolbars height, it means you have reached the bottom of the page.

Note that you should remove `1px` of retrieved height of each *fixed toolbars*.

Attach `scrollstop` listener to `document` and then define heights variables.

```
$(document).on("scrollstop", function (e) {

        /* active page */
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),

        /* window's scrollTop() */
        scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(),

        /* viewport */
        screenHeight = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),

        /* content div height within active page */
        contentHeight = $(".ui-content", activePage).outerHeight(),

        /* header's height within active page (remove -1 for unfixed) */
        header = $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight() - 1,

        /* footer's height within active page (remove -1 for unfixed) */
        footer = $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight() - 1,

        /* total height to scroll */
        scrollEnd = contentHeight - screenHeight + header + footer;

    /* if total scrolled value is equal or greater
       than total height of content div (total scroll)
       and active page is the target page (pageX not any other page)
       call addMore() function */
    if (activePage[0].id == "pageX" && scrolled >= scrollEnd) {
        addMore();
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/J4IbE9?p=info)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> Tested on iPhone 5 Safari Mobile

Comment: Why oh why isn't this method more known? How come it's not in the jQM docs? It should be!

Comment: @MarkBoulder I added links to both events. Btw, it's `scrollstop` not `scrollend`.

Comment: Please see jQM issue #7563.

Comment: @MarkBoulder `pagecreate` and `pagebeforecreate` aren't **deprecated** and both can be attached directly to any page you want!

Comment: nice one - this really helps